# Format cell background color to change prior to entered date

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

If I enter a date into a cell is there a way to have the cell background change color a few days before the date I entered?
Example:
Date entered into cell 3/26/2021 with green background
On 3/21/2021 I want the background to change to yellow.
On 3/26/2021 I want the background to change to red.

Answer (score 1):

See the code below:

#### Code:

```
function checkData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues();
  // iterate all data
  values.forEach(function(row, i){
    row.forEach(function(cell, j){
      changeColor(cell, i, j, sheet);
    });
  });
}

function onEdit(event){
  var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var range = event.source.getActiveRange();
  var cell = range.getValue();
  var i = range.getRow() - 1;
  var j = range.getColumn() - 1;

  changeColor(cell, i, j, sheet);
}

function changeColor(cell, i, j, sheet) {
  // if date object
  if(Object.prototype.toString.call(cell) === '[object Date]'){
    var today = new Date();
    // set both date to 12mn to check for day difference
    today.setHours(0,0,0,0);
    cell.setHours(0,0,0,0);
    var diffDays = (today - cell) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
    // if days remaining is 5, change to yellow
    if(diffDays == 5){
      var cellRange = sheet.getRange(i + 1, j + 1);
      cellRange.setBackground("yellow");
    }
    // if cell date is equal to today date, change to red
    if(diffDays == 0){
      var cellRange = sheet.getRange(i + 1, j + 1);
      cellRange.setBackground("red");
    }
  }
}

function createTriggers() {
  // Trigger everyday at 12mn
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('checkData')
    .timeBased()
    .everyDays(1)
    .atHour(0)
    .create();
}
```

#### Behaviour:

- If days remaining is exactly 5, change background to yellow
- If date is equal to today's date, change background to red
- Script will run when the following conditions are met:

  - When you manually edit the spreadsheet and input a date
  - Daily during 12mn (You need to run the `createTriggers` exactly once for this to be initiated)
- Daily runs checks all the cells with dates and then recalculate them, change background if necessary.
- Runs during manual edits only check the edited cell, change background if necessary.